# Uncaught TypeError: ctlLayers.addOverLay is not a function

Tags: php, ajax, leaflet, overlay

I'm trying to insert an ajax script in my index.php where I call a leaflet Methods ([addOverlay](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#control-layers-addoverlay)) **ctlLayers.addOverLay(lyrEagleNests, "Eagle Nests")** but I get this error:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: ctlLayers.addOverLay is not a function
    at Object.success (djbasin_client.php:358)
    at u (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
success @ djbasin_client.php:358
u @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
k @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
load (async)
send @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ djbasin_client.php:354
l @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
c @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
u @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
fire @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
u @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
ready @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
_ @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
```

Below I also upload the script:

```
               $.ajax({url:'load_baea.php',
                    success:function(response){
                        jsnEagles = JSON.parse(response);
                        lyrEagleNests = L.geoJSON(jsnEagles, {pointToLayer:returnEagleMarker, filter:filterEagle}).addTo(mymap);
                        ctlLayers.addOverLay(lyrEagleNests, "Eagle Nests")
                        arEagleIDs.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
                        $("#txtFindEagle").autocomplete({
                        source:arEagleIDs
                });
```

Here some images about the method:
[image]

Comment: pls share how you define `ctlLayers` and all code snippets with it

Comment: Hi @FalkeDesign, thanks for the answer. I added some images about the **ctlLayers**. If you need some more information let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have ot write `addOverlay` with a lowercase `L`:

```
$.ajax({url:'load_baea.php',
                    success:function(response){
                        jsnEagles = JSON.parse(response);
                        lyrEagleNests = L.geoJSON(jsnEagles, {pointToLayer:returnEagleMarker, filter:filterEagle}).addTo(mymap);
                        ctlLayers.addOverlay(lyrEagleNests, "Eagle Nests")
                        arEagleIDs.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
                        $("#txtFindEagle").autocomplete({
                        source:arEagleIDs
                });
```